# Rasterize does not give the same size as the original image

Tags: plotting, rasterize

I have this plot where I assigned a specific image size

```
Module[{XZ = 284, YZ = 110}, 
 plot = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -6, 6}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, FontSize -> 13}, 
   FrameStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

Then I would like to use `Rasterize` but need the output image to be the same size as the one from the plot

```
Module[{XZ = 284, YZ = 110}, 
 Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 800, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}]]
```

but the generated image is smaller? How can I make Rasterize give the same size as the original one?

[image]

Comment: `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}` is this correct? I've not seen that kind of syntax before. Are you sure you didn't mean `ImageSize -> {XZ, YZ}`

Comment: Yeah, I never liked that form.  Design mistake IMO.

Comment: @ihojnicki This form does provide an important feature which (as far as I know) is not accessible in any other way. Are there any plans to document it?

Comment: @Szabolcs, not in this form.   That much is certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make Rasterize give the same size as the original one?

Drop the `ImageSize` and `RasterSize` from `Rasterize`. Then the rasterized result will display at the same size as the original.

In order for the result to have the same pixel size, also add `ImageResolution -> 72`. On my "hidpi" screen, I get a double-resolution image otherwise (but it still displays at the correct size as the resolution is encoded into the image).

---

It is good to note that `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {x,y}` is an *undocumented* syntax that sets not the size of the entire graphics, but the size of the plot area only. This means that:

- If you use `ImageSize -> 300` then the rasterized result will be 300 pixels wide (assuming `ImageResolution -> 72`)
- If you use `ImageSize -> Automatic -> 300`, the result will be wider than 300 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Rasterize` does not understand that form.
2. Even if you move it back into the `Plot`, the coordinates are no longer accurate afterwards.  You would need to post-process the result to replace `ImageSize->Automatic->{284, 110}` with `ImageSize->Automatic`.